# Is there a one-liner that allows me to create a directory and move into it at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, cmder

I find myself repeating a lot of:

```bat
Mkdir "temp"
Cd "temp"
```

I know in Linux we have:

```bsh
mkdir "longtitleproject" && cd $_
```

Is there a similar Windows command?

Comment: `mkdir temp && cd temp`

Comment: I know that but is there any way without writing directory name

Comment: You have to write it somewhere. You could write a tiny batch file or a doskey macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
doskey cdx=md $1 $t cd $1
```

At `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` you can specify this command in the `Autorun` value. Type `doskey /?` to see how to specify multiple commands instead.

Answer (score 7):

If this is something you use a lot, the easiest option is to create a batch file that does this for you. Place the batch file in a location that is inside your `%PATH%` variable, such as `C:\Windows` and name it something that works for you, like `mcd.cmd` (make change directory)

The script would look something like this:

```bat
    @echo off

::  -- This batchfile will create a new folder and change to it.
::  -- Use: mcd <name of new folder>

::  -- Create folder:
    md "%1" 

::  -- Change to the new folder:
    cd /d "%1"
```

Here are two examples of what the script does:

```bat
C:\>mcd "My Temp"

C:\My Temp>mcd "d:\temp"

D:\temp>
```

If you don't want any errors if the folder already exists, change the md line to the following:

```bat
    md "%1" 2>nul
```

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell you can use:

```
md folder | cd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to, I recommend that you use PowerShell, as Microsoft has been pushing PowerShell over the older command line for the last several years. In PowerShell you can string multiple commands together with the `;`.

To make a new dir and move into it in one line: `md temp; cd temp`

Or my personal favorite: `gpupdate /force; gpresult /h C:Users\FriedWaffle\Desktop\result.html`

Comment: I am looking something when you create directory and change to it without input in the name of the directory

Comment: Ack, I missed your comment about not wanting to repeat the dir name a second time, my bad. Even so, I'd bet PowerShell has a way to do what you're asking.